# Prove that there exists a $\varepsilon$ such that a compact set's $\varepsilon$-neighborhood ('s closure) is compact.

Tags: general-topology

That is one of my last week's general topology exercise;

The full problem is :

> $(X,d)$ is a local compact metric space, C is a compact subset of $X$.
>
> Prove: there exists a $\varepsilon>0$ such that $V := \{v\in X | d(v,C)\le\varepsilon\}$ is a compact set.

(That is why i use the "closure" although it's not accurate).

I got stuck for 3 hours as i had no idea where to go.

Any Hints or Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: For $x\in X$ and $r>0$ let $B(x,r)=\{y\in X:d(x,y)<r\}$, the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $x$, and let $\overline B(x,r)=\{y\in X:d(x,y)\le r\}$. For each $x\in C$ there is an $\epsilon_x>0$ such that $\overline B(x,\epsilon_x)$ is compact; $\{B(x,\epsilon_x):x\in C\}$ is an open cover of $C$, and $C$ is compact, so ... ? It will also be helpful to realize that if $\epsilon\le\epsilon_x$, then $\overline B(x,\epsilon)$ is compact (why?).

Comment: So, as $C$ is compact, there is an finite cover $B(x,\epsilon_x)$. Take closure of it then it's compact cover. Besides, it's easy to prove that a closed set in compact subspace is compact. Choose the minimum $\epsilon_x$. Then we are done! Is that right?

Comment: @robothead: Sounds good!

Comment: That's really helpful!

Comment: Sorry to bother but i got some problems new. I notice that what we have done is covering the compact set $C$, but how can i clarify that $\cup_{n=1}^n\overline{B(x,\epsilon)}$ cover the $\epsilon$-neighborhood as well? I know it's true but i can't figure it out why.

Comment: @robothead: I was a little bit of ahead of myself: we actually still have to do a little work. Let $F=X\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^n B(x_k,\epsilon)$. Now all you need is a $\delta>0$ such that $B(x,\delta)\cap F=\varnothing$ for each $x\in C$. How easy this is will depend on what you’ve already proved. Have you proved that if $C$ and $F$ are disjoint closed sets in a metric space, and $C$ is compact, then $\inf\{d(x,y):x\in C\text{ and }y\in F\}>0$?

Comment: I think that can be proved by Lebesgue covering lemma : Let $C$ is a subspace of $(X,d)$, then $C$ is a compact metric subspace. So, $F^c$ is a open cover of $C$. We can use the Lebesgue covering lemma, then exist a $\delta>0$, such that $\forall x\in C, B(x,\delta)\subset F^c$, then $inf\{d(x,y)\}\ge\delta$. After prove this, we find the $\delta$, then $B(C,\delta)\subset\cup_{n=1}^n B(x_k,\epsilon)$, take the closure(can the closure be covered?) then that's completed?

Comment: By the way, is V closed?

Comment: @robothead: You can’t use the Lebesgue covering lemma that way, because it applies only to open covers of compact spaces, and $\{F^c\}$ is an open cover of $F^c$, which is not necessarily compact. The proof that comes to my mind is to suppose not; then there are points $x_n\in C$ and $y_n\in F$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)<\frac1n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. $C$ is compact, so some subsequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges to some $x\in C$. But then $\langle y_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is a sequence in $F$ converging to $x$, and $F$ is closed, so $x\in F$, contradicting $x\in C$.

Comment: I think i can complete the proof! Thanks for your solution :)

Comment: @robothead: You’re welcome.